# How to let Jersey instantiate and manage the life-cycle and let Guice perform injection

Tags: java, jersey, guice, guice-servlet

I have referred to this link for the guide on how to do it.
https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/com/sun/jersey/guice/spi/container/servlet/package-summary.html

I have followed what is shown there.
In web.xml:

```xml
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.oocl.ir4.doc.common.servlet.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
  <filter-name>GuiceFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>GuiceFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My guice config:

```java
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

  @Override
  protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {

      @Override
      protected void configureServlets() {

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "xxx.yyy");
        serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Below Resource class actually is managed by Jersey already which I don't want to be managed by Guice.  Its package is scanned by Jersey but unbound in Guice Config:

```java
package xxx.zzz;

@Path("/xxx/zzz")
public class AbcResource extends Resource {

@Inject
  private AbcServiceImpl abcService;

...
}
```

The class I want Guice to inject to resource:

```java
package xxx.yyy;

@Singleton
public class AbcServiceImpl {
...
}
```

However, it's not working.  `NullPointerException` occurs when I access the abcServiceImpl in the AbcResource.

Anyone have any hint on why or how to check what are maintained by Guice container so that I can check on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Guice to inject members in `AbcResource` you're going to need Guice to manage that class. I suspect you're going to need to add:

```
bind(AbcResource.class);
```

to your `ConfigureServlets` method. This won't interfere with any object management that Jersey performs.

Comment: Thanks @condit.  I have tried but seems it still doesn't work.  I think I would need further investigate on it.